# How to make hard edges blend in Eevee transparent emission material?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I have an emission for a supposed laser beam of a (two beams going in and out) but it just looks solid boundary. How can I remove the hard edges? I want to keept the illumination but want to get rid of edges

If this is not possible in Eevee, how could I do it, softening the edges etc?

PS: I am beginner in blender, just started using it yesterday.

Any help is gratly appreciated[image]

Comment: It looks like you have enabled the Bloom option, if you push the Emission strength it will make the object more blurry, but at the same time it will make the color brighter, which you may not want. Or you could use the Compositor to create blur on the objects you want, or on your whole scene?